# jQuery GET and Spring MVC not redirecting properly

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, redirect, spring-mvc

I have a `start.jsp` page. In it I define a jQuery click handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myButton").click(function() {
        // Injected from a Spring MVC controller returning a ModelAndView with
        // modelAndView.addObject("fizz", myFizz);
        var fizz = "${fizz}";

        // Synchronous HTTP Get to invoke page redirect.
        $.get(
            "/myWidgets",
            {
                "fizz": fizz
            },
            function(data) {
                // ???
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Then, in the controller listening at `/myWidgets`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myWidgets.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView reloadAllTimeslots(@RequestParam("fizz") String fizz) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

    // Should redirect the user to Oranges.jsp.
    mav.setViewName("fruits/Oranges");

    fruitDao.updateFruits(fizz);

    logger.info("This prints to my log file perfectly fine, so I know this handler gets invoked.");

    return mav;
}
```

However, when I am on the `start.jsp` page, and I click `myButton`, the page never redirects to `Oranges.jsp`. However the logger statement in the controller (above) prints to my server logs. So I *know* the code is working 99%, I'm just not getting the user experience I want. Anybody know why I'm not getting redirected here?

**UPDATE**:

The view resolver I'm using:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Does your project contains `fruits/Oranges.jsp` ?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani - yes `fruits/Oranges.jsp` is a JSP page in my project.

Comment: please put yur configuration of spring i.e. `applicationContext.xml` or `sprint-servlet.xml`

Comment: @BhavikAmbani - my spring context XML is *massive* - are there any bean definitions in particular you want to see?

Comment: I just want to see the redirection configuration you have mentioned in your configuration file

Comment: Well there's no redirection info in my spring context XML, and the only servlet mapping I have is in my `web.xml` where I specify `index.html` as the welcome file, and my `MyApp` controller as the servlet listening for all `*.html` requests.

Comment: I feel like this is an improper use of jQuery and Spring MVC together. The jQuery HTTP GET is synchronous, producing a page redirection. Yet the server has its own story of how redirection should work. I think the wrong one is "winning" the argument, somehow...

Comment: Does your spring configuration have view resolver ?

Comment: Is your view file located at `/WEB-INF/views/fruits/Oranges.jsp` ?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani - yes, it's at that exact path... frustrating, isn't it!?

Comment: Are you trying to redirect to another page inside of an ajax request? I guess this can't be done at least that: 1. Stop using the ajax call and use a normal HTTP request, 2. Return the page where you want to redirect in the ajax `success` js function and do the redirect from there using plain javascript.

Comment: @HeineyBehinds Thank you for not putting your massing XML config :) In the future if you want to share big code files you can use https://gist.github.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page is not going to change history or go load a different URL (oranges) because you are using AJAX. In fact most people use AJAX like this for [single-page-application](/questions/tagged/single-page-application) behavior.

If you want the page to reload you just use normal FORM submition ie something like:

```
<form action="/myWidgets" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="fizz" value="${fizz}" />
<button type="submit">Click</button>
</form>
```

The above requires no jQuery.

If you want to load the page but using AJAX and have the URL change then you should look at something like PJAX (pushstate history).

You should also avoid the term `redirect` when you mean routing (or page loading) particularly for HTTP scenario. Redirect for most web developers means HTTP 301 which is very common for traditional form POST submission but not at all what your doing above.

Answer (score 0):

For this task, the best way to do that redirection (as Luiggi mentioned in the comment) is to redirect by javascript after the ajax function return success from the server. You can never redirect by an ajax request only. For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myWidgets.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String reloadAllTimeslots(@RequestParam("fizz") String fizz) {
    fruitDao.updateFruits(fizz);

    logger.info("This prints to my log file perfectly fine, so I know this handler gets invoked.");

    return "success";
}
```

and in the HTML file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myButton").click(function() {
        var fizz = "${fizz}";

        // Synchronous HTTP Get to invoke page redirect.
        $.get(
            "/myWidgets",
            {
                "fizz": fizz
            },
            function(data) {
                // ???
            }
        ).success(function() { window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com"); })
         .error(function() { alert("error"); })
         .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
    });
});
```